# Noun for somebody that is eloquent/a good public speaker?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What would you call somebody that has a strong way with words, especially in terms of public speaking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An *orator*.   The definition is a public speaker, particularly one who is skilled and forceful with their words.

[Source](http://i.word.com/idictionary/orator)

Answer (score 0):

There is **[elocutionist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elocutionist)** also.

> a public speaker trained in voice production and gesture and delivery

---

And a little passage from the [history of speech](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/%7Educhan/new_history/hist19c/elocution.html):

> The success of lyceums attests to the value Americans placed on elocution and oratory early in the 19th century. In keeping with this emphasis a number of individuals began providing elocution lessons for those interested in improving their own ways of speaking, reading aloud, giving oral presentations, or singing.
>
> **Elocutionist was the name given to both those who performed orations themselves and those who taught others how to perform.** These US specialists in oral presentation called themselves elocutionists, following the already established elocution movement in the United Kingdom.

Comment: Elocution has more to do with the formation of the words than the ability to select powerful words for public speaking. It is a great word, though.

Comment: @David M: Orator is a common usage for a public speaker but the question suggests for an eloquent speaker as well. Luckily, "eloquent" and "elocution" have the same roots so elocutionist ideally suited.

Comment: I actually don't see the word eloquent anywhere in the OP's question.  But, orator implies eloquent as well.  Click on the [source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orator) in my answer, and you will see it implied in the definition.  You wouldn't call just anyone who walks up to a microphone an orator.  You'd just call them a speaker.

Comment: Orator came to my mind as an answer too, as you already gave it as an answer, I wanted to give elocutionist as an alternative answer. "orator" can mean a public speaker and a good public speaker also. I did not mean that orator is not eloquent. I'm just giving extra information about etymology. "eloquent" is in the title by the way.

Comment: Oops!  Missed that!  And who down voted this?  It's an apt word, it just misses the mark by a hair.

Answer (score 0):

Well the professional job they would have would be **announcer** or **host** and in the broadest sense, **politician**.

In clubs there is often a **toastmaster**.

For the literary types you could use **rhetorician**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the quality of their approach to oratory, you could call them:

a [rhetor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Rhetor?s=t), a [logodaedalist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logodaedaly?qsrc=2446), a [logomaniac](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logodaedaly?qsrc=2446), or a [logorrheic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logodaedaly?qsrc=2446).